# How to open a MS Word Document (.doc) in Matlab programatically at a specific section

Tags: matlab, ms-word

Again, the main problem is jumping to a specific section.

Comment: I doubt that you can easily do that, short of writing your own parser for the .doc format, which is proprietary.  Matlab is really good at reading data from text files, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried?

I found this on the file exchange...

[link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28558-control-ms-word-from-matlab)

it might do the job?

Comment: Actually this activity is frozen right now, but after It's back your link should be the first thing I try. Thanks!